# calling BaseAdapter's notifyDataSetChanged() inside CustomAdapter not refreshing ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I have `ArrayList<MyObject> data` which is populated on the `ListView` using a `CustomAdapter`.

I've implemented `View.OnClickListener` in the `CustomAdapter` class and clicking a button deletes the particular row. After deleting the row, both from database and from the `data` object using `data.remove(i)` inside the Custom Adapter, I call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Problem is that it does not refresh teh `ListView`.

I'm using a tabbed activity with fragment. So, when go to some distant tab and come back to this tab, it refreshes the `ListView` and the deleted item does not show anymore.

Why is the `ListView` not refreshing immediately when i call `notifyDataSetChanged()` but changing when i move to another fragment and back?

My `CustomAdapter` class is as follows:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context context;
    private ArrayList<MyObject> data;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyObject> data) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....
    .....

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        int id = data.get((Integer) v.getTag()).id;
        //use getTag() to get the position, set position in tag before adding listener.
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.txtName:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Show Details" + v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.btnRemove:
                db.removePaper(id); // works fine
                data.remove(v.getTag()); // works fine
                notifyDataSetChanged(); // PROBLEM HERE: Does not refresh listview
                break;
            case R.id.btnFavorite:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Favorite" + v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: After deleting the data (row) reload list from db or set data again to listView.

Comment: @SohailZahid I know that will work. I am not looking for a workaround. I want to know why the `notifyDataSetChanged()` isn't refreshing the list.

Comment: Because it has the same data to inflate in list.

Comment: no it does not. `data.remove(v.getTag());` removes the element from data object.

Comment: your onClick in your activity?

Comment: after deleting you have to again set your adapter with deleted data.

Comment: i think you have not understood the problem. The data changes inside the adapter itself, not outside. I dont think the same thing needs to be reassigned within the CustomAdapter class.

Comment: Thats why i ask you this before. try this context.notifyDataSetChanged() will solve your problem.

Comment: your data model is sqlite db based, right? so use `SimpleCursorAdapter`, not a custom one

Comment: @SohailZahid that method is not in the Context class. cannot be called using context object. :-)

Comment: @pskink context is just used here for referencing here because you are in onClick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue some time ago, I fixed it extending `ArrayAdapter<MyObject>` instead of `BaseAdapter` and overriding some methods:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject> {

private List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

 @Override
 public void add(MyObject obj) {
     this.list.add(obj);
     super.add(obj);
 }

 @Override
 public void remove(MyObject obj) {
     int i = getPosition(obj);
     if(i >= 0)
         list.remove(i);
     super.remove(obj);
 }

 @Override
 public void clear() {
     this.list.clear();
     super.clear();
 }

 @Override
 public MyObject getItem(int position) {
     return this.list.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public int getPosition(MyObject obj) {
     for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
         if(list.get(i).equals(obj))
             return i;
     }
     return -1;
 }}
```

Then call these methods instead of calling directly methods of your List.